# TSQL XML Modify error with XSD

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xsd

Good day,

The following test is working:

```
    DECLARE @XmlTest TABLE
    ( ID int,
      MyContent Xml
    )

    declare @aaa XML

    set @aaa = '<Root><MyNode Qualifier="0" Code="AAA" Deleted="true">9.99</MyNode><MyNode Qualifier="0" Code="AAA"         Deleted="false">10.99</MyNode></Root>'
    insert into @XmlTest (ID, MyContent)
    values(1,@aaa)
    set @aaa = '<Root><MyNode Qualifier="0" Code="BBB" Deleted="false">9.99</MyNode></Root>'
    insert into @XmlTest (ID, MyContent)
    values(2,@aaa)

    select * from @XmlTest
```

-- The node selection [@Code="AAA" and @Deleted="false"] is unique, so I want to be able to "delete it" logically

```
    UPDATE @XmlTest
    SET MyContent.modify('replace value of (/Root/MyNode[@Code="AAA" and @Deleted="false"]/@Deleted)[1] with true()')
    WHERE ID = 1

    select * from @XmlTest
```

But with a XSD, It does not work. I have an error message like

Msg 2234, Niveau 16, État 1, Ligne 19
XQuery [@XmlTest.MyContent.modify()]: Operator "=" cannot be applied to "" and "xs:string"

Here is the schema and new declaration of my table

```
    DECLARE @XmlTest TABLE
    ( ID int,
      MyContent Xml(CONTENT TestSchema)
    )


    DROP XML SCHEMA COLLECTION TestSchema

    create xml schema collection TestSchema as
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">
    <xs:simpleType name="AmountType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
            <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="9999999999"/>
            <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="Root" sql:is-constant="1">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="MyNode" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" sql:is-constant="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="AmountType">
                                <xs:attribute name="Qualifier" use="required">
                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                       <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                           <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                       </xs:restriction>
                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                </xs:attribute>
                                <xs:attribute name="Code" use="required">
                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:maxLength value="15"/>
                                        </xs:restriction>
                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                </xs:attribute>
                                <xs:attribute name="Deleted" use="required">
                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:boolean">
                                           <xs:pattern value="true"/>
                                           <xs:pattern value="false"/>
                                        </xs:restriction>
                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                </xs:attribute>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>'
```

I tried this modification but if failed the same way:

```
    <xs:attribute type="xs:boolean" name="Deleted" use="required" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Change deleted definition to

```
<xs:attribute type="xs:boolean" name="Deleted" use="required" />
```

I don't know why you would want to do it in another way.

The reason the query still does not work is because you are comparing the boolean `@Deleted` with the string `"false"`. Use `false()` instead.

```
replace value of (/Root/MyNode[@Code="AAA" and @Deleted=false()]/@Deleted)[1] 
with true()
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael for your reply. I think I mislead myself with the restriction "true" or "false" (did not want to accept 0 or 1). Your solution is working only if I remove the restriction in the XSD (and I don't mixup type).

Comment: @DenisGilbert if you want only "true" and "false" you should use xs:string as base. But then I think you have to use a string both in comparison and assignment. Ie you need to change  `with true()` to `with "true"`